# iPhone - Xcode - Invalid CFArrayRef when searching Address Book for a symbol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, addressbook

I'm trying to filter contacts using a search bar each time a user enters a character. This works fine for regular characters, but when a symbol is entered like $ or ( for the first character, ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName returns an "Invalid CFArrayRef". I've searched a while for the solution and I can't seem to find anything. The code is below.

```
    CFArrayRef filteredContacts = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, (CFStringRef)searchText);
    CFMutableArrayRef filteredContactsMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFArrayGetCount(filteredContacts), filteredContacts);
    CFArraySortValues(filteredContactsMutable, CFRangeMake(0, CFArrayGetCount(filteredContactsMutable)), (CFComparatorFunction)ABPersonComparePeopleByName, (void*)sortOrdering);
    contacts = (NSArray *)filteredContactsMutable;
    CFRelease(filteredContacts);
```

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the second line where filteredContactsMutable is created using filteredContacts. When I debug it, filteredContacts is an Invalid CFArrayRef when a symbol is the ***first*** character. The native PeoplePicker created by Apple allows you to search a symbol as the first character, so I know it's possible.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea? Is it reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

first you should not trigger too much OS calls when you start search. load all data once and store it into array then search. and the reason why it crashes it due to nil argument in it cz i thnk no such user name find. try with simple charectrs n tell me if this prblm still exists

Comment: If I enter Q as the first letter, it does not crash, despite the fact that I have no contacts with the letter Q. My tableView is cleared out, as expected. It only happens with symbols it seems.